# l-------l.com, a weird web page from 2000

Tags: internet

I remember a mysterious web page from 2000 with the domain name `l-------l.com`. This domain name goes against [RFC 5891](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5891#section-4.2.3.1) but it was valid back in the day. It's pretty hard to search for this. Most search engines decide I want to know about "L".

The Internet Archive has a few [crawls](https://web.archive.org/details/http://www.l-------l.com/) of it, but it only contains a little HTML. Looks like the content was actually in
[Macromedia Shockwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Shockwave) DCR files that were not crawled.

What I remember about the contents is that there was no text (or very little) and the pages were mostly just a single bold color. Clicking on something would take you to another such page. It seemed to be a labyrinth of hyperlinks. So mysterious!

Is there any chance this would be archived somewhere, or I could find any further information?

Comment: This is the only mention I could find of it from the period; lots of other fun sites on this list too https://web.archive.org/web/20000121210828/http://www.azstarnet.com/~imagicra/receptor.html

Answer (score 10):

It might interest you to know that variants of the domain name with five, six
and eight dashes contain the same content. The title tag in all of them shows seven so I assume that's the correct name.

The site's embed.html attempts to load something called 'redline.dcr', and that name appears elsewhere in the source so I assume the site is for something or someone calling themselves Redline.

The only other piece of content I can find is a html select box which offers a selector of eighteen American cities all given a nickname, with the JavaScript code swapping in an image related to each city. When I first saw the list I thought they might be track names from an album but I can't find anything that matches the names.

Comment: Redline was apparently a video game released in 1999 by a company called Accolade.  That release date would match the late 1998 - 2000 dates for l-------l.com that I'm seeing in the Wayback Machine.  I don't know if this is just a coincidence or not.  Here's the Wikipedia link for the game Redline: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redline_(1999_video_game)

Comment: That's interesting. I looked at some manuals and boxes for Redline and could only see accolade.com not l-------l.com though.

Comment: Yes, it’s just an idea suggested by the dates. I don’t really have any non-circumstantial evidence for it.